# server side get request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I am making request to Coursera api on client side but because of CORS it gets blocked. And Jsonp also not working because api is returning json data.

I have mostly worked with client side so dont know much about server side requests.

How can I get api data using node and then use that data to create webpage.I am using Angular on front end.

I have seached about how to make GET request in node and I got some answers also (using http module). But simply dont know how to connect the front end ?

Comment: Show us the API code please

Comment: provide here your code

Comment: Which one ? the code I used on the front end which failed or the answers I have found for server side GET request. For the latter case I can give you the links I have found but they are just simple example codes to make GET requests using node and http module.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to setup a local host, shouldn't be too hard with nodejs.

Comment: @Invictus, when you are getting json data, its pretty easy to bind that in angular view using the ng-repeat tag...

Answer (score 0):

```
require('http')
```

HTTP Module Docs : https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Usage :

```
    http.get({
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 80,
  path: '/',
  agent: false  // create a new agent just for this one request
}, (res) => {
  // Do stuff with response
});
```

Get API code (not tested)

```
http.get({
    hostname: 'https://api.coursera.org',
    port: 80,
    path: '/api/courses.v1',
    agent: false
}, (res) => {
    res // your json data
});
```

Comment: There are two things first I want to access [this end point] (https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1) 
second how to use that fetched data into html.
I mean just like we do on client side